# Safely terminating USB data lines

Tags: usb, usb-device

On one of my PC USB ports, I am using the power lines only, to drive a relay module that switches other devices on and off in sync with the PC.  This is working well.

The two data lines I have left floating, but I think they are getting stray interference that is bothering the computer, because for the first few minutes after power on, I get continual notification sounds of device connected/disconnected, before it gives up on that port and ignores it.

How can I terminate the data lines safely so the PC knows that there is no device active on it?  Should I:

- connect them together?
- tie them together with a resistor?
- connect them to the power ground line?

Comment: Leave them unconnected, preferably at the PC end.  For this to be happening it sounds like you've got some serious EMI going on.  Perhaps you are unreasonably abusing the USB as a power supply.

Comment: I can't get to the PC end, it's standard moulded cable that I've cut the remote end off.  It's just a regular domestic environment as far as EMI is concerned.  I'm thinking the data lines should be tied to something to give them a definite low?

Comment: No, that is not how USB works.  The data lines should float.  If you are experiencing EMI problems, it is likely that your load is the source of the problems.  Probably you should not be abusing the USB to power it, but rather using a dedicated power supply.  If you have to monitor the USB VBUS state, use a choke or an optocoupler to keep the grunge of your load from coupling back to it.

Comment: Do these issues occur when the relay module is sitting idle, or when the relay module is switching?

Comment: @alpha, only at startup.  The relay activates when the PC is powered on or wakes, then releases at power off or sleep.  There is no issue at wake/sleep so I assume the PC only rechecks the port at power on, then marks it as somehow suspect and ignores it from then on.

Comment: Does the relay module specify the current and voltage it requires?

Comment: Relay module takes 5v, draws 80mA.  A fairly modest load I think, since USB2 can supply 500mA and this is a USB3 port, should be capable of 1A.  Open/close of relay with PC is working exactly as I intended, only that PC seems to be thinking there is some data entity on the end of it.

Comment: Try adding a capacitor across the USB power pins on the relay module. As close to the USB connector as possible. If you can try soldering it to the pins of the USB connector. If there is HF noise which is upsetting your computer this will prevent it from getting out through the USB connector to your computer. A physically small ceramic capacitor (0603) would be best, but try whatever you have on hand.

Comment: Thanks for thoughts, Chis and alpha.  Further investigation suggests I may be guilty of assuming this was related to the relay module wiring.  But now it seems it is actually due to a faulty hub, that is not always powered on in my environment, and so does not always create this issue.  Disconnecting that hub makes this all go away.